# Convert bytes to a string in Julia

Tags: julia

I would like to convert a Vector of bytes to a string. E.g.

```
[0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65]

[0xe4, 0xbd, 0xa0, 0xe5, 0xa5, 0xbd] # or non-ASCII characters
```

Should be converted to:

```
"abcde" # [0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65]
"你好" # [0xe4, 0xbd, 0xa0, 0xe5, 0xa5, 0xbd]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just call the inbuilt `String` constructor function:

```
  String(v::AbstractVector{UInt8})

  Create a new String object from a byte vector v containing UTF-8 encoded characters.
```

```
julia> [0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65] |> String
"abcde"

julia> String([0xe4, 0xbd, 0xa0, 0xe5, 0xa5, 0xbd])
"你好"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `decode` function in the `StringEncodings` library, together with an encoding of your choice (UTF-8 in this example). This will produce the desired string.

```
using StringEncodings

encodings() # will show all supported encodings

decode([0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65], "UTF-8")
# "abcde"

decode([0xe4, 0xbd, 0xa0, 0xe5, 0xa5, 0xbd], "UTF-8") 
# "你好"
```